# Persistent bar at the bottom or above bottomNavigationBar (if it exists)

Tags: flutter

I have a persistent bar across all the pages in my app that always stays on top irrespective of where I am. For this, I am doing the below:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: TestPage(),
      initialRoute: "/test",
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              child!,
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: routes(context),
    );
  }
}
```

But as you can expect, this puts this bar at the very bottom. I want it above the `bottomNavigationBar`. So I can change the `Positioned(bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight)`, which kinda works. But then it also affects all the pages which don't have a bottom navigation bar, and leaves empty space below the bar. Is there a way to place it above the `bottomNavigationBar` on page where it exists, and at the bottom where it doesnt?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Widget out of the `Stack()` widget you created and pass in a boolean function that determines whether to add `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` to `bottom` or use `0` instead. Then, when defining routes, use that widget to determine if it needs the extra height or not.

```dart
class PinnedBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
 final bool hasBottomNavBar;
 final Widget child;

 const PinnedBottomBar({
   required this.hasBottomNavBar,
   required this.child,
   super.key,
 });

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Stack(
     children: [
       child,
       Positioned(
         left: 0,
         right: 0,
         bottom: hasBottomNavBar ? kBottomNavigationBarHeight : 0,
         child: Placeholder(),
       ),
     ],
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple. If you notice in my post, I am persisting the same instance of the PinnedBottomBar by calling it in the MaterialApp directly. This is intentional as I don't want navigation between pages to interfere or change this instance. So doing it per page is not a solution for me :(.